# mysql many-to-many query issue

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

i have many to many database and i'm there is a query that i just got stuck with and cant do it.

i have 4 tables **Artists**, **Tracks**, **Albums**, **Clips**

now i'm on the artist page so i need to get them by the artist page, i already got all of them, but not the way i want them.

because some tracks, albums, clips belong to other artists as well (duet) and i need to display their name.

but the problem is that i'm selecting using the artist id so my GROUPC_CONCAT function wont work here is the query that gets the artist albums.

```
   SELECT  al.album_name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.artist_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'artist_name'

   FROM 
     Albums al
   LEFT JOIN 
     ArtistAlbums art ON art.album_id = al.album_id
   LEFT JOIN 
     Artists a on a.artist_id = art.artist_id
   WHERE 
     a.artist_id = 10
   GROUP BY 
     al.album_id
```

one of the albums have two artists attached to it, but it does not get the other artist name.

when i select by the album_id i get the two artists.

please note that i'm new to mysql and i did not find any answers on this particular problem almost no resources on many-to-many querying.

how can i tackle this problem.?

any resources or books on many-to-many that show how to deal with the database on the application layer will be much appreciated,
thanks in advance.

Comment: You have stated explicitly what artist's data to fetch (`a.artist_id = 10`) so you'll get results for this artist, not for others

Comment: yeah and i also said that this is the problem i'm having, how can i get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of table aliases as really being *row aliases*.  That is, for purposes of expressions in the WHERE clause and the select-list, the alias refers to a single row at a time.

Since you've created a condition such that `a.artist_id = 10`, then only rows for that artist match the condition.  What you really want is to match all artists on an album given that one artist is artist_id = 10.

For that, you need another join, so that the row where artist_id = 10 is matched to *all* the rows for that respective album.

```
SELECT  al.album_name, GROUP_CONCAT(a2.artist_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS `artist_name`
FROM 
  Albums al
INNER JOIN 
  ArtistAlbums art ON art.album_id = al.album_id
INNER JOIN 
  Artists a on a.artist_id = art.artist_id
INNER JOIN 
  ArtistAlbums art2 ON art2.album_id = al.album_id
INNER JOIN 
  Artists a2 on a2.artist_id = art2.artist_id
WHERE 
  a.artist_id = 10
GROUP BY 
  al.album_id
```

P.S.: I've also replaced your use of LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN.  There's no reason you needed LEFT JOIN, since you're explicitly looking for albums that have a matching artist, not all albums whether or not it has artist 10.  [Review the meaning of different types of join.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

Re your followup question:

I don't know of a book specifically about many-to-many queries.  I'd recommend books like:

- [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/), which is my own book and it does cover many-to-many tables.
- [SQL and Relational Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596523068) to understand joins better.
- [Joe Celko's SQL Programming Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120887975), which imho is Joe Celko's best book.

Comment: Heh, I was half-way through writing this exact answer -- you beat me to the punch =)

Comment: I thank Mrs. Wilcox, my touch-typing teacher in high school, for my speed.  :-)

Comment: thanks, and i gotta ask what book will you recommend on many-to-many ?!